# How to enable Speex codec on microphone object in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, encoding

From what I have read, using Speek over Nellymoser [is advantageous](http://askmeflash.com/article/2/speex-vs-nellymoser), but I can't figure out how to use it with a Flex 4 Microphone object.

For instance, the last code line:

```
private var oMicrophone:Microphone;    
oMicrophone = Microphone.getMicrophone ();
oMicrophone.codec = "Speex"
oMicrophone.encodeQuality (8)
```

Gives me this compile error:

> Attempted access of inaccessible
>   method encodeQuality through a
>   reference with static type
>   flash.media:Microphone

I am not impressed with [Adobe's documentation on this](http://www.eonflex.com/flex/4.1/langref/flash/media/Microphone.html#encodeQuality).

Guess I either need to import something or include some extra module that doesn't come with the Flex SDK - or...?

Comment: I never heard of either Speek or Nellymoser, however I would have expected they would come w/ their own instruction set and you would use those codecs/APIs instead of the Adobe APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `encodeQuality` is a property, not a method. To use it, just assign a value to it:

```
private var oMicrophone:Microphone;    
oMicrophone = Microphone.getMicrophone ();
oMicrophone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX //Use an enumerator class
oMicrophone.encodeQuality = 8;
```

That seems to take care of it.

Comment: Doooooh! What a silly mistake. Sometimes, thinking you know what the problem is the problem itself. Thanks a million!